# Grid security in grid frameworks

Tags: security, grid, acl

Recently, I've become quite involved experimenting with lightweight grid frameworks (Hazelcast, Gigaspaces, Infinispan).

However, I've been somewhat surprised than none of the free frameworks I tried has any ACL or role based security features built in (Gigaspaces does have some measures).

What approaches are generally used to compensate for this? Am I supposed to only use the grid to share data between trusted server-side applications and use the traditional Java EE stack (i.e. a conventional DAO-layer) to access data from client or non-trusted server applications?

Are there any grid frameworks that provide ACL capabilities for accessing data in the grid (I'd be happy with some ad-hoc stuff, although complying to Java EE role concepts would be nice)?

Answer (score 0):

This is my opinion on current state of open source distributed cache solutions (e.g. JBoss  Cache and Infinispan). As a baseline I am using GigaSpaces commercial caching product. Let me know what you think about open source and proprietary cache products.

read more at: http://bigdatamatters.com/bigdatamatters/2009/09/infinispan-vs-gigaspaces.html